# JPA: finding class from table name

Tags: inheritance, jpa, orm

I have a `documents` table

```
CREATE TABLE `documents` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`docnum` int(11) default null,
`docdate` DATE default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and corresponding Documents @Entity. Then I have a `orders`, `invoices` and other similar tables that have 1-to-1 relationship with `documents`. Documents entity declares joined inheritance and derived Orders, Invoices,... entities use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. Everything works as expected.

Then I have a table that establishes some weak relationship between various documents types:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `documents_xref` (
  `id` int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
  `xrefdate` DATE not null,
  `src_doc` int(11) not null,
  `src_doc_tablename` VARCHAR(250) not null,
  `dst_doc` int(11) not null unique,
  `dst_doc_tablename` VARCHAR(250) not null,
  INDEX(`src_doc`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`src_doc`) REFERENCES `documents` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`dst_doc`) REFERENCES `documents` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Now I need to display a graph of relationships between documents, and each node of the graph must tell what type of document it is, so that I need to find the @Entity class from the table name. Is there a way other than brute force to obtain it from JPA2?

On a side note: could anyone with 1500 rep create the "joined-inheritance" tag for me if he feels like doing so and attach it to my question? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be provider specific, as you would need to access the internal JPA meta-data, unless you process all of the annotations/xml yourself, or define your own hard coded map between tables and classes.

For EclipseLink you can unwrap the EclipseLink Session from the EntityManagerFactory and access all of the descriptors.

```
for (ClassDescriptor descriptor : emf.unwrap(Session.class).getDescriptors().values()) {
  Class entityClass = descriptor.getJavaClass();
  List<String> tables = descriptors.getTableNames();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Hibernate but I don't want to bind my code to it nor to any other provider. I'm going to process annotations myself then.